# Access component from service

Tags: angular

In angular 2, is it possible to access the calling component (component that is calling the service) from the service?

Let's say my component is:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
    providers: [Service]
})

export class MyComponent{

    constructor(private service:Service) {
        service.accessComponent();
    }

    callMe(){
        console.log('hello');
    }
}
```

And my service would be:

```
@Injectable()

export class Service{
    accessComponent(){
        var myComponent = ???;

        myComponent.callMe();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are losing a point of responsibilities. You should service to host business logic, and components are just logic to help you deal with templates. It is difficult to figure out without domain, what you are trying to solve, give us real task.

Comment: @Mikki I'm trying to add eventListeners to my component's elements...`componentElement.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
                myComponent.clickMe();
            }, false);`

Comment: Ok, I see, but why do you need service, in such case, could you update your code, and I will try to rewrite it in the proper way

Comment: @Mikki BTW, I can easily send the element and the function to my service and everything works but the problem is when I call the service function multiple times for different element. the eventListener disappears for all the elements except the last one

Comment: @Mikki I need the service because it a long function that is used a dozen of times in different components

Comment: so you want to call some long function on click of different components elements? am I right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125277/discussion-between-mikki-and-ncohen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not use `addEventListener`, because to handle click, angular2 has it's own way to do that - `<div (click)="calledFunc()"></div>`. It is idiomatic way to add click event in angular2. (According to comment discussion)

Comment: Yes but my element is dynamically added using `innerHTML` so I can't use `(click)`...

Comment: This doesn't even answer the original question. How is this the accepted answer?

Comment: XD haha, this is a great answer to the wrong question.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong to call component from service. You shuold call service in component! this is architecture of angular 2.  [read this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html)

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {
    accessComponent() {
        alert('Hi!');
    }
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
    providers: [Service]
})
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(private service: Service) {
        service.accessComponent(); // and you see alert!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve that, you could create Subject in service and emit `next` on it in the service.

Then subscribe to the subject in your component, calling the method once stream will emit the value.